# Did Walter become Millennium's servant by choice?

Tags: anime, hellsing-anime

Walter tells Victoria that he was brainwashed and forcefully turned into Millenium's minion, but then says that he attacks what remains of Hellsing by his own free will. *Bad* characters usually mess with *good* ones, so it's not clear how it really happened to him.

Also see: [Did Walter become Millennium's Servant by choice? @ Anime and Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2055/did-walter-become-milleniums-servant-by-choice)

Comment: Sorry we couldn't answer your question. If you're still interested, there is a new Stack Exchange site, [anime.se], where you might find a more focused audience for this question. If you decide to ask there, please link the questions to each other (so that people seeing the question on one site can also go and see answers on the other site).

Comment: Thanks, [I just did that](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2055/did-walter-become-milleniums-servant-by-choice).

Comment: @Gilles: according to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), it should be migrated, rather than asked on both sites. Right?

Comment: @JNat it says in the bottom of the accepted answer: `Note: I do not consider any sites valid migration targets until they are out of public beta. There are no guarantees that a current SE site will live past beta.`

Comment: @user1306322: yes, but what you did is considered abusive behaviour, according to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu#comment181805_75012), since you copy-pasted it.

Comment: @JNat According to the same poster as you just referred to, my question is actually more tailored for the Anime and Manga SE site, so I wouldn't outright call it abusive just because some people say it may be, without going into details. If you have any suggestions on how I sould edit my question to better fit A&M, please let me know.

Comment: @user1306322: I understand, I just think it should be migrated. I know Beta sites aren't guaranteed to succeed, but attracting new users is a good way to ensure they do. Let's see what the mods think. And I didn't mean to say your behaviour was abusive in a bad way, it's just the way it is written in that same comment. :)

Comment: @JNat Given how little attention the question has had here, I don't think anyone would regret it if it got migrated. Migrating to a beta sites risks losing the answers if the beta site closes, but here there are no answers. But questions that are older than 2 months can no longer be migrated, so the point is moot for this question: if it's to find a life elsewhere, it has to be re-asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after Walter tells Seras that he was brainwashed, he follows it up with "Is that what you wanted to hear?" Implying that this story is a lie and that he is making fun of her shock at his betrayal. Also he says that he has wanted to defeat Alucard for a very long time, implying that he planned his betrayal. This is further evidenced from when he says "I thought it was you" when he is "captured" by the Captain. From all of this, it seems that he really did join by free will.